# Is the correct: "Employee.where(age: <"60").order(:first name)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use 'Employee.where(age: <"60").order(:first name)'. It is not working. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your :age field is an integer and you need to order by :first_name it goes like this:

```
Employee.where('age < ?', 60).order(:first_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look [into documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html). You will find the descriptions to each ActiveRecord query method, including [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) and [`order`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
#Controller
@employees = Employee.sort_by_name('first_name ASC').young_employees

#model
scope :sort_by_name, ->(criteria) { order: criteria }
scope :young_employes, -> { where("age < ?", 60)}
```

In order to this to work, please check that your 'age' columns is integer type, and also that your first name columns is called 'first_name'

Comment: While it is a good idea to extract some logic into scopes, the naming choices here are atrocious.

Comment: lol yea, Im terrible naming things when programming, well I just took like 2 minutes for write the answer so I did not take too much time for think about names, any suggestion? let me know I will edit the answer. Regards!